# Ubuntu 14.10 no caching page found on all hard drives

Tags: caching

Ubuntu 14.10 no caching page found on all hard drives 2 sata and two ide  also same if I mount avusb drive

After upgraded from 14.04.1 and also from a clean install of 14.10

During boot I get error on all hard drives no caching page found. I never had this problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and below yet on 14.10 it exists and cripples the performance of the system?

The exact error during boot is:

A TPM error(7) occured
Trying to read a pcr value

ata4 srst failed (errorno=-16)

sddd no caching mode page found
sddd assuming disk write through
sdde no caching mode page found
sdde assuming disk write through

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a serious error, it is not actually an error at all. All that this indicates is that your drive's SCSI mode pages don't contain an entry for caching. A mode page allows reading metadata related to the device, and changing the settings of the device, for example, to disable or enable write caching.
>
> In this case, your device does not provide information about any underlying write caching mechanism. This could be for a variety of reasons, most likely that either the device may be passed through an interface which presents itself as a SCSI device, but does not expose any cache (for example, if you were exposing the drive using a USB enclosure), or the device may simply have no cache (although this seems to not be true for your particular device).

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138396/is-no-caching-mode-page-a-serious-error)

Comment: But it is crippling the system also it is switching to write through mode. This is happening to all drives not just one?

Comment: You could try another kernel, but I'm not sure it'll help. _crippling the system_ is no error description btw...

Comment: If it is unsortable I will have to go back to 14.04.1 and never upgrade past 14.04.1?

Comment: By crippling the system I mean the entire system is slow and in responsive especially installations of any software or packages